# RDLC grouping rows

Tags: rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I'm trying to do a rdlc table/matrix gruoping by Id.
I have a DataSet which is returning:

Id | name | price | quantity | subtotal | comment

The comment column is optional,also it can have multiple comments per Id so it could return duplicate rows but with different comment column.

Then I want to display in a Table or matrix the data like this

Id | name | quantity | price | subtotal

```
                   comment
```

[image]

I mean adding additional rows per comment.
Is it possible to display rows in that format?
If so, What is the best way to achieve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can easily be achieved by using `RowGroups`. For your example you'd want a stepped report.

Here is an excellent tutorial from MSDN that should be of use to you:
[Create a Stepped Report (Report Builder and SSRS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220467.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot!

Comment: Do you know  scope expression for the visibility of the textboxes?

Comment: When I have a row duplicated in the exppresion SUM(Fields!SubTotal.Value, "PurchaseOrderDataSet") it took me the values twice